# How can i convert a dataframe with a factor column to a xts object?

Tags: r, finance, xts

I have a csv file and when i use this command

```
SOLK<-read.table('Book1.csv',header=TRUE,sep=';')
```

I get this output

```
> SOLK
          Time Close Volume
1   10:27:03,6  0,99   1000
2   10:32:58,4  0,98    100
3   10:34:16,9  0,98    600
4   10:35:46,0  0,97    500
5   10:35:50,6  0,96     50
6   10:35:50,6  0,96   1000
7   10:36:10,3  0,95     40
8   10:36:10,3  0,95    100
9   10:36:10,4  0,95    500
10  10:36:10,4  0,95    100
.      .         .       .
.      .         .       .
.      .         .       .
285 17:09:44,0  0,96    404
```

Here is the result of `dput(SOLK[1:10,])`:

```
 > dput(SOLK[1:10,])
structure(list(Time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("10:27:03,6", "10:32:58,4", "10:34:16,9", 
"10:35:46,0", "10:35:50,6", "10:36:10,3", "10:36:10,4", "10:36:30,8", 
"10:37:23,3", "10:37:38,2", "10:37:39,3", "10:37:45,9", "10:39:07,5", 
"10:39:07,6", "10:39:46,6", "10:41:21,8", "10:43:20,6", "10:43:36,4", 
"10:43:48,8", "10:43:48,9", "10:43:54,6", "10:44:01,5", "10:44:08,4", 
"10:45:47,2", "10:46:16,7", "10:47:03,6", "10:47:48,6", "10:47:55,0", 
"10:48:09,9", "10:48:30,6", "10:49:20,6", "10:50:31,9", "10:50:34,6", 
"10:50:38,1", "10:51:02,8", "10:51:11,5", "10:55:57,7", "10:57:57,2", 
"10:59:06,9", "10:59:33,5", "11:00:31,0", "11:00:31,1", "11:04:46,4", 
"11:04:53,4", "11:04:54,6", "11:04:56,1", "11:04:58,9", "11:05:02,0", 
"11:05:02,6", "11:05:24,7", "11:05:56,7", "11:06:15,8", "11:13:24,1", 
"11:13:24,2", "11:13:32,1", "11:13:36,2", "11:13:37,2", "11:13:44,5", 
"11:13:46,8", "11:14:12,7", "11:14:19,4", "11:14:19,8", "11:14:21,2", 
"11:14:38,7", "11:14:44,0", "11:14:44,5", "11:15:10,5", "11:15:10,6", 
"11:15:12,9", "11:15:16,6", "11:15:23,3", "11:15:31,4", "11:15:36,4", 
"11:15:37,4", "11:15:49,5", "11:16:01,4", "11:16:06,0", "11:17:56,2", 
"11:19:08,1", "11:20:17,2", "11:26:39,4", "11:26:53,2", "11:27:39,5", 
"11:28:33,0", "11:30:42,3", "11:31:00,7", "11:33:44,2", "11:39:56,1", 
"11:40:07,3", "11:41:02,1", "11:41:30,1", "11:45:07,0", "11:45:26,6", 
"11:49:50,8", "11:59:58,1", "12:03:49,9", "12:04:12,6", "12:06:05,8", 
"12:06:49,2", "12:07:56,0", "12:09:37,7", "12:14:25,5", "12:14:32,1", 
"12:15:42,1", "12:15:55,2", "12:16:36,9", "12:16:44,2", "12:18:00,3", 
"12:18:12,8", "12:28:17,8", "12:28:17,9", "12:28:23,7", "12:28:51,1", 
"12:36:33,2", "12:37:45,0", "12:39:22,2", "12:40:19,5", "12:42:22,1", 
"12:58:46,3", "13:06:05,8", "13:06:05,9", "13:07:17,6", "13:07:17,7", 
"13:09:01,3", "13:09:01,4", "13:09:11,3", "13:09:31,0", "13:10:07,8", 
"13:35:43,8", "13:38:27,7", "14:11:16,0", "14:17:31,5", "14:26:13,9", 
"14:36:11,8", "14:38:43,7", "14:38:47,8", "14:38:51,8", "14:48:26,7", 
"14:52:07,4", "14:52:13,8", "15:09:24,7", "15:10:25,8", "15:29:12,1", 
"15:31:55,9", "15:34:04,1", "15:44:10,8", "15:45:07,1", "15:57:04,9", 
"15:57:13,9", "16:16:27,9", "16:21:41,7", "16:36:01,5", "16:36:13,2", 
"16:46:10,5", "16:46:10,6", "16:47:37,3", "16:50:52,4", "16:50:52,5", 
"16:51:44,5", "16:55:11,5", "16:56:21,8", "16:56:37,5", "16:57:37,9", 
"16:58:18,6", "16:58:44,5", "17:00:39,1", "17:01:50,7", "17:03:13,2", 
"17:03:28,3", "17:03:46,7", "17:03:47,0", "17:04:30,4", "17:08:41,8", 
"17:09:44,0"), class = "factor"), Close = structure(c(8L, 7L, 
7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0,92", "0,93", "0,94", 
"0,95", "0,96", "0,97", "0,98", "0,99"), class = "factor"), Volume = c(1000L, 
100L, 600L, 500L, 50L, 1000L, 40L, 100L, 500L, 100L)), .Names = c("Time", 
"Close", "Volume"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The first column includes the time stamp of every transaction during a stock's exchange daily session.  I would like to convert the Close and Volume columns to an xts object ordered by the Time column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: From your edits, it appears you imported your data using two different commands.  It also appears you should be using `read.csv2`.  I've updated my answer with `Lines` that (I assume) look more like your original CSV (I have to guess because you don't say what the file looks like).  The rest of the answer doesn't change.

You have to add a date to your times because xts stores all index values internally as `POSIXct` (I just used today's date).

I had to convert the "," decimal notation to the "." convention (using `gsub`), but that may be locale-dependent and you may not need to.  `paste` today's date with the (possibly converted) time and then convert it to `POSIXct` to create an index suitable for xts.

I've also formatted the index so you can see the fractional seconds.

```
Lines <- "Time;Close;Volume
10:27:03,6;0,99;1000
10:32:58,4;0,98;100
10:34:16,9;0,98;600
10:35:46,0;0,97;500
10:35:50,6;0,96;50
10:35:50,6;0,96;1000
10:36:10,3;0,95;40
10:36:10,3;0,95;100
10:36:10,4;0,95;500
10:36:10,4;0,95;100"

SOLK <- read.csv2(con <- textConnection(Lines))
close(con)

solk <- xts(SOLK[,c("Close","Volume")],
  as.POSIXct(paste("2011-09-02", gsub(",",".",SOLK[,1]))))
indexFormat(solk) <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6"
solk
#                            Close Volume
# 2011-09-02 10:27:03.599999  0.99   1000
# 2011-09-02 10:32:58.400000  0.98    100
# 2011-09-02 10:34:16.900000  0.98    600
# 2011-09-02 10:35:46.000000  0.97    500
# 2011-09-02 10:35:50.599999  0.96     50
# 2011-09-02 10:35:50.599999  0.96   1000
# 2011-09-02 10:36:10.299999  0.95     40
# 2011-09-02 10:36:10.299999  0.95    100
# 2011-09-02 10:36:10.400000  0.95    500
# 2011-09-02 10:36:10.400000  0.95    100
```

Comment: Joshua when i apply the command `solk <- xts(SOLK[,c("Close","Volume")],
  as.POSIXct(paste("2011-09-02", gsub(",",".",SOLK[,1]))))` i get this `> solk
                    Close  Volume 
2011-09-02 10:27:03 "0,99" " 1000"
2011-09-02 10:32:58 "0,98" "  100"
2011-09-02 10:34:16 "0,98" "  600"
2011-09-02 10:35:46 "0,97" "  500"
2011-09-02 10:35:50 "0,96" "   50"
2011-09-02 10:35:50 "0,96" " 1000"
2011-09-02 10:36:10 "0,95" "   40"
2011-09-02 10:36:10 "0,95" "  100"
2011-09-02 10:36:10 "0,95" "  500"
2011-09-02 10:36:10 "0,95" "  100"`

Comment: .The str() command gives me this output `str(solk)
An 'xts' object from 2011-09-02 10:27:03 to 2011-09-02 17:09:44 containing:
  Data: chr [1:285, 1:2] "0,99" "0,98" "0,98" "0,97" "0,96" "0,96" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Close" "Volume"
  Indexed by objects of class: [POSIXct,POSIXt] TZ: 
  xts Attributes:  
 NULL`.The mode of the columns Close and Volume seems to be character `sapply(solk, mode)
      Close      Volume 
"character" "character"`. How can i convert them to numeric?

Comment: @user861288: the `SOLK` object in your comments isn't the same as the one in your original question.  Please update your question.  Adding `dput(SOLK[1:10,])` would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

That's an odd structure.  Translating it to `dput` syntax

```
SOLK <- structure(list(structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L), .Label = c("10:27:03,6", "10:32:58,4", "10:34:16,9", "10:35:46,0", 
"10:35:50,6", "10:36:10,3", "10:36:10,4"), class = "factor"), 
    Close = c(0.99, 0.98, 0.98, 0.97, 0.96, 0.96, 0.95, 0.95, 
    0.95, 0.95), Volume = c(1000L, 100L, 600L, 500L, 50L, 1000L, 
    40L, 100L, 500L, 100L)), .Names = c("", "Close", "Volume"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

I'm assuming the comma in the timestamp is decimal separator.

```
library("chron")
time.idx <- times(gsub(",",".",as.character(SOLK[[1]])))
```

Unfortunately, it seems `xts` won't take this as a valid `order.by`; so a date (today, for lack of a better choice) must be included to make `xts` happy.

```
xts(SOLK[[2]], order.by=chron(Sys.Date(), time.idx))
```