# Bubble Chart in R with # of Occurrences / Sums of Values

Tags: r

I'm playing around with drawing bubble charts in R -- the current project is to graph a bubble chart of political donations that has the following characteristics:

```
x-axis: size of donation, in ranges i.e. $10-$19, $20-29, $30-49, etc.
y-axis: number of donations of that amount
area of bubble: total amount of donations
```

I'm not planning anything complex, just something like:

```
symbols(amount_ranges,amount_occurrences, circles=sums)
```

The data is pretty granular, so there is a separate entry for each donation and they need to summed in order to get the values I'm looking for.

For example, the data looks like this (extraneous columns removed):

```
CTRIB_NAML    CTRIB_NAMF    CTRIB_AMT    FILER_ID
John          Smith         $49          123456789
```

This is not that complex, but is there a simple way in R to count up the number of occurrences of a certain value (for the y-axis)?  And to add up sum of those donations (which is derivative of the axes)?  Or do I need to create a function that iterates through the data and compiles these numbers separately?   Or pre-process the data in someway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ddply` from package `plyr` here. If your original data.frame was called `dfr`, then something close to this should work:

```
result<-ddply(dfr, .(CTRIB_AMT), function(partialdfr){data.frame(amt=partialdfr$CTRIB_AMT[1], sm=sum(partialdfr$CTRIB_AMT), mn=mean(partialdfr$CTRIB_AMT)) })
```

In fact, a base R solution is also rather simple:

```
vals<-sort(unique(dfr$CTRIB_AMT))
sums<-tapply( dfr$CTRIB_AMT, dfr$CTRIB_AMT, sum)
counts<-tapply( dfr$CTRIB_AMT, dfr$CTRIB_AMT, length)
```

I'm sure more elegant solutions exist.

Comment: Maybe I should add this as a separate question, but how should I convert the CTRIB_AMT column to a numeric column, so the `sums` and `counts` can calculate properly.  I tried `as.numeric(as.character(sub("$",'',contribs$CTRIB_AMT)))` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299991/how-can-i-convert-a-factor-column-that-contains-decimal-numbers-to-numeric) but that didn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It should be pretty close. What problems do you get?

Comment: Oh, I see, you need: `as.numeric(as.character(sub("$","",contribs$CTRIB_AMT, fixed=TRUE)))` because `$` is a special character in regular expressions (see `?sub`)

Comment: Great.  That replaced the '$' character but still the column is a factor instead of numeric column.  I've got to keep working on this, but if you have any ideas...

Comment: Sigh. `contribs$CTRIB_AMT<-as.numeric(as.character(sub("$","",contribs$CTRIB_AMT, fixed=TRUE)))`. Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is easy when you use the `ggplot2` package with `geom_point`.

One of many benefits of using `ggplot` is that the built-in statistics means you don't have to pre-summarise your data.  `geom_point` in combination with `stat_sum` is all you need.

Here is the example from `?geom_point`.  (Note that `mtcars` is a built-in dataset with `ggplot2`.)

See [the ggplot website](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) and [geom_point](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_point.html) for more detail.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point(aes(size = qsec))
```

[image]