# Read csv file in R with currency column as numeric

Tags: r, currency, symbols, read.csv

I'm trying to read into R a csv file that contains information on political contributions.  From what I understand, the columns by default are imported as factors, but I need the the amount column ('CTRIB_AMT' in the dataset) to be imported as a numeric column so I can run a variety of functions that wouldn't work for factors.  The column is formatted as a currency with a "$" as prefix.

I used a simple read command to import the file initially:

```
contribs <- read.csv('path/to/file')
```

And then tried to convert the CTRIB_AMT from currency to numeric:

```
as.numeric(as.character(sub("$","",contribs$CTRIB_AMT, fixed=TRUE)))
```

But that didn't work.  The functions I'm trying to use for the CTRIB_AMT columns are:

```
vals<-sort(unique(dfr$CTRIB_AMT))
sums<-tapply( dfr$CTRIB_AMT, dfr$CTRIB_AMT, sum)
counts<-tapply( dfr$CTRIB_AMT, dfr$CTRIB_AMT, length)
```

See related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329733/bubble-chart-in-r-with-of-occurrences-sums-of-values).

Any thoughts on how to import file initially so column is numeric or how to convert it after  importing?

Comment: A small example of the file contents would be helpful.

Comment: The `sub` -> `as.character` -> `as.numeric` conversion should do the trick.  What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: Works for me. `CTRIB_AMT <- factor(c("$5000","$2500","$100"));
as.numeric(as.character(sub("$","",CTRIB_AMT, fixed=TRUE)))`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not sure how to read it in directly, but you can modify it once it's in:

```
> A <- read.csv("~/Desktop/data.csv")
> A
  id   desc price
1  0  apple $1.00
2  1 banana $2.25
3  2 grapes $1.97
> A$price <- as.numeric(sub("\\$","", A$price))
> A
  id   desc price
1  0  apple  1.00
2  1 banana  2.25
3  2 grapes  1.97
> str(A)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id   : int  0 1 2
 $ desc : Factor w/ 3 levels "apple","banana",..: 1 2 3
 $ price: num  1 2.25 1.97
```

I think it might just have been a missing escape in your sub. $ indicates the end of a line in regular expressions. \$ is a dollar sign. But then you have to escape the escape...

Comment: I initially thought there was a missing escape too, but `fixed=TRUE` takes care of that ...

Comment: +1  
I also found `gsub( "[$,]", "",` . . . useful for figures like `"$1,234"`.

Comment: This should not be the accepted solution; it is inferior to other solutions which do the substitution at read-time, at read-time, return numeric, and thus avoid creating lots of unnecessary and unique strings, which could waste Mb/Gb on a large file, and also be slower.

Answer (score 14):

Another way could be setting conversion using `setAs`.
It was used in two (similar) question:

- [Processing negative number in "accounting"
  formatR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068705/processing-negative-number-in-accounting-format-in-r/5069649#5069649)
- [How to read a csv file where some numbers contain
  commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523126/how-to-read-a-csv-file-in-r-where-some-numbers-contain-commas/3611619#3611619)

For your needs:

```
setClass("Currency")
setAs("character", "Currency",
    function(from) as.numeric(sub("$","",from, fixed=TRUE)))

contribs <- read.csv("path/to/file", colClasses=c(CTRIB_AMT="Currency"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Yet another solution for a problem solved long time ago:

```
convertCurrency <- function(currency) {
  currency1 <- sub('$','',as.character(currency),fixed=TRUE)
  currency2 <- as.numeric(gsub('\\,','',as.character(currency1))) 
  currency2
}

contribs$CTRIB_AMT_NUM <- convertCurrency(contribs$CTRIB_AMT)
```

Answer (score 4):

Taking advantage of the powerful parsers the `readr` package offers out of the box:

```
my_parser <- function(col) {
  # Try first with parse_number that handles currencies automatically quite well
  res <- suppressWarnings(readr::parse_number(col))
  if (is.null(attr(res, "problems", exact = TRUE))) {
    res
  } else {
    # If parse_number fails, fall back on parse_guess
    readr::parse_guess(col)
    # Alternatively, we could simply return col without further parsing attempt
  }
}

library(dplyr)

name <- c('john','carl', 'hank')
salary <- c('$23,456.33','$45,677.43','$76,234.88')
emp_data <- data.frame(name,salary)

emp_data %>% 
  mutate(foo = "USD13.4",
         bar = "£37") %>% 
  mutate_all(my_parser)

#   name   salary  foo bar
# 1 john 23456.33 13.4  37
# 2 carl 45677.43 13.4  37
# 3 hank 76234.88 13.4  37
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use something like `as.numeric(substr(as.character(contribs$CTRIB_AMT),2,20))` we know that there certainly won't be more than 20 characters.

Another thing to note is that you can remove the need to convert from a factor alltogether if you set `stringsAsFactors=F` in your call to `read.csv()`

Answer (score 0):

A more modern answer now perhaps:

`read_csv` from the `readr` package has a `col_number()` parser that can deal with comma separators and currency symbols.

Just used it to parse some stock data downloaded from NASDAQ:

```
# Downloaded from https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/amzn/historical
AMZN <- 
  read_csv("data/AMZN_HistoricalData_1640763915240.csv", 
    col_types = cols(
      Date = col_date(format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
      `Close/Last` = col_number(),
      Volume = col_integer(),
      Open = col_number(),
      High = col_number(),
      Low = col_number())
  )
```