# Getting rid of the #### to NA error while settting Column Class in r data frame

Tags: r, excel, csv, dataframe, na

I am working with a csv file which was originally formatted in excel. I want to convert the rate column into numeric and remove the "$" sign.

I read in the file with :
`> NImp <- read.csv("National_TV_Spots 6_30_14 to 8_31_14.csv", 
                   sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
                      strip.white=TRUE, na.strings=c("Not Monitored"))`

The data frame looks like this:

```
HH.IMP..000.       ISCI                                          Creative          Program  Rate
1           NA     IT3896 Rising Costs30 (Opportunity Scholar - No Nursing)      NUVO CINEMA $0.00
2           NA     IT3896 Rising Costs30 (Opportunity Scholar - No Nursing)      NUVO CINEMA $0.00
3          141    IT14429 Rising Costs30 (Opportunity Scholar - No Nursing)            BONUS $0.00
4          476 ITES15443H     Matthew Traina (B. EECT/A. CEET) :60 (no loc) Law & Order: SVU $0.00
5           NA     IT3896 Rising Costs30 (Opportunity Scholar - No Nursing)      NUVO CINEMA $0.00
```

When I do do the conversion, I get an error message: `> NImp$Rate <- as.numeric(gsub("$","", NImp$Rate))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion` and all values get coerced to NAs.

I also tried, `NImp$Rate <- as.numeric(sub("\\$","", NImp$Rate))` but again got the same warning message. However not all values became NAs - only specific ones. I opened the csv in excel to check and I realized that excel forces csv column width too narrow resulting in "####" cells. These cells are being coerced to "NA" by `r`.

I tried the option of opening the file in notepad and read the notepad file into `r`. But I get the same results. The values are correctly displayed in both Notepad and when I read the file into `r`. But when I change to numeric, everything that shows as "####" in excel, becomes `NA`.

What should I do?

Adding `str(NImp)`

```
'data.frame':   9859 obs. of  19 variables:
$ Spot.ID         : int  13072903 13072904 13072898 13072793 13072905 13072899 13072397 13072476 13072398 13072681 ...
$ Date            : chr  "6/30/2014" "6/30/2014" "6/30/2014" "6/30/2014" ...
$ Hour            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 ...
$ Time            : chr  "12:08 AM" "12:20 AM" "12:29 AM" "12:30 AM" ...
$ Local.Date      : chr  "6/30/2014" "6/30/2014" "6/30/2014" "6/30/2014" ...
$ Broadcast.Week  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ Local.Hour      : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 ...
$ Local.Time      : chr  "12:08 AM" "12:20 AM" "12:29 AM" "12:30 AM" ...
$ Market          : chr  "NATIONAL CABLE" "NATIONAL CABLE" "NATIONAL CABLE" "NATIONAL CABLE" ...
$ Vendor          : chr  "NUVO" "NUVO" "AFAM" "USA" ...
$ Station         : chr  "NUVO" "NUVO" "AFAM" "USA" ...
$ M18.34.IMP..000.: int  NA NA 3 88 NA 3 NA 53 NA 37 ...
$ W18.34.IMP..000.: int  NA NA 86 66 NA 86 NA 70 NA 60 ...
$ A18.34.IMP..000.: int  NA NA 89 154 NA 89 NA 123 NA 97 ...
$ HH.IMP..000.    : int  NA NA 141 476 NA 141 NA 461 NA 434 ...
$ ISCI            : chr  "IT3896" "IT3896" "IT14429" "ITES15443H" ...
$ Creative        : chr  "Rising Costs30 (Opportunity Scholar - No Nursing)" "Rising Costs30 (Opportunity Scholar - No Nursing)" "Rising Costs30 (Opportunity Scholar - No Nursing)" "Matthew Traina (B. EECT/A. CEET) :60 (no loc)" ...
$ Program         : chr  "NUVO CINEMA" "NUVO CINEMA" "BONUS" "Law & Order: SVU" ...
$ Rate            : chr  "$0.00" "$0.00" "$0.00" "$0.00" ...
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. `as.numeric(sub("\\$", "", df$Rate))` works for me

Comment: I'm not sure what causes the problem, but 1) "\\$" is the right regular expression to use ($ just matches the end of a string) and 2) the way excel displays the csv file is irrelevant, so don't worry about the ####

Comment: The "####" cell is actually "$1200.00". The csv files are formatted in excel. IF I save it as notepad, the rows and columns go for a toss - something to do with a comma value I guess. Excel reduces the column width of "$1200.00" and it becomes "####" which `r` reads as `na`. Its confounding.

Comment: The ### is just the way Excel displays it - if you increase the width of the column it will show the actual value, so it's irrelevant. Check your export options when you export to csv from Excel , what do you mean "the rows and columns go for a toss"?

Comment: No, It appears fine in Notepad and in `r`. But the moment i change to numeric and remove $ in `r`, I still get NAs where the CSV showed #### in excel. Even if i read in the csv from notepad.

Comment: OK, can you post the output of `str(NImp)` after reading it in R and before you do any operations on it?

Comment: done ! I just tried saving the using Google Drive into CSV . But same problem. any cell which excel forces to "####" by reducing the column width becomes "NA" .

Comment: I can reproduce this when the value in the csv file looks like `$1,200.00`.  If you remove the dollar sign and try to make this numeric you will get `NA`.  You need to remove the commas, as well, before you can convert to numeric.  You can do this with `as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", ...))` (found code in a comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7338251/2461552)).

Comment: @aosmith That worked ! post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a column was set as "Currency" in Excel, the values in the thousands or greater have a comma in them as well as the dollar sign prefix.  For example, a value might look like `$1,200.00`.  The problem you were having was because you were removing the dollar signs but not the commas, so when you tried to convert to `numeric` you get `NA`.

```
as.numeric(c("0", "0", "1,200"))
[1]  0  0 NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

You can remove the dollar signs and commas in one step using `gsub`.  I found an example of how to do this in a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337824/read-csv-file-in-r-with-currency-column-as-numeric/7338251#7338251).

```
as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", c("$0", "$0", "$1,200")))
[1]    0    0 1200
```

So the code that should work for your dataset is

```
as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", NImp$Rate))
```

Comment: that's exactly what happened. Every number with Comma had that problem.

Comment: related: I have certain values in the NImp$Rate column which are already plain numeric like "4167". Applying above function turns them into NAs. Any solution to selectively apply?

Comment: @vagabond I can't reproduce - `as.numeric(gsub("[$,]", "", c("$0", "$0", "$1,200", "4167")))` works for me.  Maybe ask a new question?