# R import numbers but don't round

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a `.csv` file where columns `2` and beyond are dollar amounts such as `$1004.23`, `($1482.40)`, `$2423.94`, etc. Similar to the example below:

```
id   desc    price
0    apple   $1.00
1    banana  ($2.25)
2    grapes  $1.97
```

When I bring in this file using the below command, all of my numbers get rounded so `$1.00` becomes `$1` and `($2.25)` becomes `($2)`.

```
df <- read.csv(file.path(path = path, file = "filename"), header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, dec=".")
```

I've tried it without the `dec="."` option to no avail.

Comment: Interesting It does not round off for me. Possible that it is not truncating but when you printing dataframe it is resulting truncation. try `print(df, digits=5)`

Comment: This is more related to your Q.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337824/read-csv-file-in-r-with-currency-column-as-numeric

Comment: This isn't reproducible as written. Can you `dput` an excerpt from the file and show the rounded output?